# Should I use slippy tile folders to display a map when having a large set of information?

Tags: tiles, mapnik

I have about 1 million polygons divided into 3 ShapeFiles, each of them having 2GB, a total of 6GB. If I generate 256x256 tiles from zoom level 8 to 17, I will have 25 millions of tiles (image files) and about 200GB of folders and images.

Afterward, I can display the tiles with leaflet using Slippy Tile format: http://server.com/z/x/y.png. The frontend app would just request image files to a static bulk instead of using any Map Server (GeoServer, Mapnik or MapServer).

Is this a good strategy when it comes to a large set of spatial information as I have? Or should I use something more robust like GeoServer or mapnik?

If I have 10k users a day, will I have good performance accessing files directly?

**UPDATE**
I've updated the question to clarify it.

Comment: The answer depends on what you need to do with the files. If you just want to view it with fixed rendering, and the time/space tradeoff is worth it to you, then pre-rendering could be worth it. Alternatively, you could render on demand. Or you could use a vector tiling approach. The intended use, and the users' needs (alternative styling? filtering? additional processing?) are key issues you need to describe in your question to get useful answers.

Comment: Fixed rendering, no styling, no filtering and no additional processing. As simple as possible. Fixed tiles would be good, however, my concern here is: is it really practical to have 25 millions of tiles? Is there any recommended limit max amount of tiles when using slippy tiles format?

Comment: How many users you will have?

Comment: Probably 10k users a day after launching. Afterward, around 2k users a day.